React useEffect not updating context state correctly with socket.io and context API
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/toast";
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import { Context } from "../context/StateProvider";

const Home = () => {
  const SideBar = lazy(() => import("../components/SideBar"));
  const BG = lazy(() => import("../components/BG"));

  const toast = useToast();

  let {
    setIsAuthenticated,
    friends,
    getAllFriends,
    getProfile,
    setOnlineUsers,
    socket,
    onlineUsers,
  } = useContext(Context);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  const [localOnline, setLocalOnline] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("http://localhost:3000", { query: { token } });

    function validateAuth() {
      if (token) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        getProfile();
        getAllFriends();
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    }
    validateAuth();

    function makeConnection() {
      if (token) {
        socket.current.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("Connected");
        });

        socket.current.on("update-active-users", (arr) => {
          // console.log("Listening updated users");
          setLocalOnline(arr);
        });

        socket.current.on("join-room", (roomID) => {
          toast({
            title: "Enjoy Chatting with your freind",
            status: "info",
            duration: 2000,
            position: "bottom",
          });
        });

        socket.current.on("error", (error) => {
          toast({
            title: error.name,
            position: "bottom",
            status: "error",
            duration: 3000,
            isClosable: true,
            description: error.message,
          });
          if (
            error.name === "JsonWebTokenError" ||
            error.name === "TokenExpiredError"
          ) {
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            navigate("/auth");
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
            return;
          }
        });
      } else {
        navigate("/auth");
      }
    }

    makeConnection();

    return () => {
      if (socket.current) {
        socket.current.disconnect();
        socket.current.on("disconnect", (id) => {
          toast({
            title: `User ${id} left the chat`,
            duration: 2000,
            status: "info",
            position: "bottom",
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   socket.current.emit("check-active-users");
  //   console.log("Called on friends changing");
  // }, [friends.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    friends.forEach((fr) => {
      if (localOnline.includes(fr.friend_id)) {
        setOnlineUsers((prev) => [...prev, fr.friend_id]);
      }
    });
  }, [friends.length]);

  // const online = useCallback(() => {
  //   setIsRefresh(!isRefresh);
  // }, [onlineUsers.length]);

  // console.log(onlineUsers);

  // online();
  console.log("Home Rendered");
  // console.log("Friends in Home: ", friends);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen w-screen">
      <div className="flex h-full w-full">
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <SideBar />
        </Suspense>
        <div className=" h-full w-full bg-[#1F1F22]">
          <div className=" absolute  h-full overflow-hidden w-full">
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
              <BG />
            </Suspense>
          </div>
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Home);

okay as you guys can see i have a state from context  as friends and some methods also so i was trying to fetch friends and profile first then want to connect the socket to backend and want to check that is there any online users from current user's friendlist so i can set the active users from  current user's friends  so when i try to do that still till that time the friends state is not updated even when i tried call it earlier so when i try update active users till that friends are empty it gets updated after that . I know that state update is async in react but i have tried chatgpt and some of other tools but still i didn't getting solution. So help me out

I think the problem may be in your Context, perhaps the changes in the friends variable are not being listened to by the Context but as I don't know how your context is implemented I refactored the code to ensure that the calls follow the desired sequence, as I assume that the getProfile and getAllFriends methods are async, the code below ensures that the calls finish first before the socket is configured
I also modified the useEffect of friends to listen to localOnline and added logic so that it only calls setOnlineUsers once.
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/toast";
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import { Context } from "../context/StateProvider";

const Home = () => {
  const SideBar = lazy(() => import("../components/SideBar"));
  const BG = lazy(() => import("../components/BG"));

  const toast = useToast();

  let {
    setIsAuthenticated,
    friends,
    getAllFriends,
    getProfile,
    setOnlineUsers,
    socket,
    onlineUsers,
  } = useContext(Context);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [localOnline, setLocalOnline] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("http://localhost:3000", { query: { token } });


    const asyncInit = async () => {
      // Validate Auth
      if(token){ // Authenticated flow

        setIsAuthenticated(true);

        //Get init info
        await getProfile(); // wait get profile info
        await getAllFriends();

        //Socket listeners
        socket.current.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("Connected");
        });

        socket.current.on("update-active-users", (arr) => {
          // console.log("Listening updated users");
          setLocalOnline(arr);
        });

        socket.current.on("join-room", (roomID) => {
          toast({
            title: "Enjoy Chatting with your freind",
            status: "info",
            duration: 2000,
            position: "bottom",
          });
        });

        socket.current.on("error", (error) => {
          toast({
            title: error.name,
            position: "bottom",
            status: "error",
            duration: 3000,
            isClosable: true,
            description: error.message,
          });
          if (
            error.name === "JsonWebTokenError" ||
            error.name === "TokenExpiredError"
          ) {
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            navigate("/auth");
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
            return;
          }
        });

      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        navigate("/auth");
      }
    }

    setLoading(true)
    asyncInit()
      .catch(() => {
        ///TODO handle errors
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false) // remove loading from screen
      });

    return () => {
      if (socket.current) {
        socket.current.disconnect();
        socket.current.on("disconnect", (id) => {
          toast({
            title: `User ${id} left the chat`,
            duration: 2000,
            status: "info",
            position: "bottom",
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }, []);

 // Memoize the filtered list of online friends to avoid re-creating the reference
  const filteredOnlineUsers = useMemo(() => {
    return friends.filter(fr => localOnline.includes(fr.friend_id));
  }, [friends, localOnline]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOnlineUsers(filteredOnlineUsers.map(fr => fr.friend_id));
    
  }, [filteredOnlineUsers, localOnline]);

  // const online = useCallback(() => {
  //   setIsRefresh(!isRefresh);
  // }, [onlineUsers.length]);

  // console.log(onlineUsers);

  // online();
  console.log("Home Rendered");
  // console.log("Friends in Home: ", friends);

  if(loading){
    return (
      <div>loading...</div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="h-screen w-screen">
      <div className="flex h-full w-full">
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <SideBar />
        </Suspense>
        <div className=" h-full w-full bg-[#1F1F22]">
          <div className=" absolute  h-full overflow-hidden w-full">
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
              <BG />
            </Suspense>
          </div>
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Home);


I was just about to answer but I see your edit clears it.. Its almost certain the core problem is localOnline missing in the deps array. Otherwise that effect will reference stale values and the evaluation of onlineUsers will be therefore incorrect. However, this onlineUsers state item and the effect shouldn't even exist really. He should do that in render or useMemo -- as this is a classic misuse of an effect. Rather than add noise with another answer that's on the same tracks I can suggest an edit via SO to your answer if you like? :).

Yes, i agree, and yes, you can suggest an edit

Ah apparantly my rep means it instant edits instead of suggests lol , but feel free to further refine/change.

Actually removed for now, as I just realised the onlineUsers is actually up in context somewhere. The remodel is bigger as the online status needs computing up in the provider ideally. And its hard to suggest the ideal change via code without him providing the provider code as you originally hinted.

but passing friends or localOnlineUsers in deps array may cause issue because it's non-primitive and have reference value which will be different of every render  so the useEffect will re-render several times

You have to use React.useMemo to avoid recreate the references, i updated the code adding useMemo before  as deps of useEffect
